# Java NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror

For an assignment at school, I need to make a class `Blender` that implements some pre-defined things. I received a JAR file, `imagecompositor.jar`, that does everything and makes use of the `Blender` class. The JAR file contains two classes (`ImageCompositor.class` and `StDraw.class`).

To run the program, the teachers say that I have to run the following:

```
java -cp ... ass3.ImageCompositor img1 img2 offsetx offsety
```

I only know how to code Java. I have no idea how to load external classes into a JAR file. So I tried this:

```
java -cp imagecompositor.jar ass3.ImageCompositor img1.png img2.png 0 0
```

but it threw a `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ass3/Blender
at ass3.ImageCompositor.main(ImageCompositor.java:113)
```

The `Blender` class has the line `package ass3` in it. What am I doing wrong?

I want to give more information, but I don't know how to get the stack trace, etc.

Comment: What's going on at line 113 of ImageCompositor?  The java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is usually some static constructor failing.  We need more of the stacktrace to try to figure this out or a peek at ImageCompositor to figure out what in the constructor chain is crapping out.

Comment: We do not get the source code of the assignment. We only get the jar file, so I can not tell you what happens there. But it's probably Blender blender = new Blender(); as that's where it first complains about not finding the Blender class definition.

Comment: Where did you see the exception message?  Generally the stack trace comes out immediately after that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `Blender` class to the classpath.

The command line

```
java -cp imagecompositor.jar ...
```

uses a classpath of imagecompositor.jar. This tells the Java virtual machine (JVM) to look in the jar file. What it doesn't tell the JVM to do is to look for your classes. If you've packaged them into a jar file, you should do

```
java -cp imagecompositor.jar;myclasses.jar ...
```

and if the .class files are in a tree with root directory `path/to/someRoot` (e.g. class `ass3.Blender` should be in `path/to/someRoot/ass3/Blender.class`), then you should use the same syntax but with the root directory rather than a .jar file (I *think* this is right, can't find docs):

```
java -cp imagecompositor.jar;path/to/someRoot ...
```

Comment: The solution you describe fixes java.lang.ClassNotFoundException but not java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is usually some static constructor failed.  We need more of the stacktrace to try to figure this out.

Comment: True, Bob. I actually tried this already, but it didn't work (give the same error). Also : the jar files have to be separated by a colon...

Answer (score 0):

Where is the Blender class located?  To be found properly, your the Blender class (in package "ass") must be located in a directory named "ass" relative to your current directory.  If it is (and you do not remove the current director `.` from the default class path) then you do not need to modify your class path.

**However**, in your case you need to modify the class path (in order to specify the supplied jar file), and command listed in your post **does** remove `.` from the path.  So you must do the following:

```
    java -cp whatever.jar;. whatever_other_parameters
```

(Note the ";." appended to the -CP argument.)  This puts the current directory back in the class path.

Comment: The solution you describe fixes java.lang.ClassNotFoundException but not java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (Jason's answer has the same issue). java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is usually some static constructor failed. We need more of the stacktrace to try to figure this out.

Comment: Yeah, NoClassDefFoundError is only due to the named class being totally missing in a small minority of cases.  More often it's due to a different class being missing, a class version mismatch, or a static initialization problem.  You need at least the first ten lines or so of the traceback to sort it out.

Comment: Thank you Bob :), that is true. tried this too in the past, didn't work.

Comment: @Korion -- Bob said "we need more of the stacktrace".  We still do.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is usually a failure in the static constructor.  The JVM would say java.lang.ClassNotFoundException if it couldn't locate your class at all.  From your question description, I'm thinking the commandline is:

```
java -cp imagecompositor.jar ass3.ImageCompositor img1 img2 offsetx offsety
```

which is assuming that the imagecompositor.jar file is in the same directory as where we are executing the java command.  This is telling the java compiler to make everything in imagecompositor.jar available to the classloader and we are loading a class named ImageCompositor which resides in the ass3 package.  We are also assuming that the ImageCompositor has a static main method, which is how Java runs stuff from the commandline.